# Android: corner border stroke getting hidden behind imageview

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-layout, android-imageview

hello I'm trying to add a corner to my constraint layout so the logic is whenever from the response I'm not getting the image I will show text else image but whenever the image comes corner stroke is getting hidden in the `imageview`

problem image:-

[image]

here is my code:

```
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraint_rt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_115sdp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W,16:9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:padding="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/rt_list_img_gradient_bg_with_stroke"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtpopularRT"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/worksans_semibold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/klgreen"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageRt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

drawable file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:startColor="@color/black"
    android:endColor="@color/new_black_1"
    android:angle="270" />
<stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/kred" />
<corners
    android:radius="10dp">
</corners>
```

please help me out with how can I show the stroke at the corner

any help will be appreciated

Comment: updated answer you can check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Image is hiding stroke border because your `drawable` or background shape of `constraint` layout have `corners` radius so if you notice in your image only corner parts are being hidden so you can fix by also adding corners to image. You can do by wrapping `ImageView` in `CardView` and giving corner radius to that cardview something like this -

**UPDATED CODE :**

```
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraint_rt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_115sdp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W,16:9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:padding="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/rt_list_img_gradient_bg_with_stroke"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtpopularRT"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/worksans_semibold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/klgreen"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

             <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/imageRt"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:adjustViewBounds="true"
              android:scaleType="fitXY"
              android:visibility="gone" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**INFO :**

I have added `10dp` of corner radius because your shape drawable have the same radius - `10dp`.

P.S - Alternative You can also use [RoundedImageView](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView#roundedimageview)